# simple rails helper gives "NoMethodError"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, helper

helpers/subcategories_helper.rb:

```
module SubcategoriesHelper
  def has_topic_headings?
    self.topic_headings
  end
end
```

categories/show.html.erb contains

```
          <% @category.subcategories.each do |subcategory| %>
            <li>
              <h6>
                <%if subcategory.has_topic_headings? %>
                  <%= link_to subcategory.name, subcategory, data: :has_topic_headings %>
                <% else %>
                  <%= link_to subcategory.name, subcategory %>
                <% end %>  
              </h6>
              <hr>
            </li>
          <% end %>
```

The page returns

```
undefined method `has_topic_headings?' for #<Subcategory:0xa68748c>
```

Please note that the view page belongs to the Category, not the Subcategory.

Comment: First let me know what your self.top_headings will return?

Comment: 2.0.0p247 :018 > s.topic_headings
 => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to call it on model which is why it is not called on when helper is included. Helpers are there for views and sometimes for controllers.

Comment: Thank you, I tried to include this in both Categories and Subcategories controllers, but I get the exact same error. I also tried including the function in the Subcategory helper_method.

Comment: Oops! you are calling it on subcategory. Its wrong. You have to call it without it and it will check the same function on controller object. If you want to call it on model, please write this function in model.rb. Helpers are not for models.

Comment: @techvineet  First check the error before answering the question.

Comment: My apologies. Lemme know if you need any further help

Comment: The method showing in error and the method defined in helpers are different.

Comment: Are'nt they same? has_topic_headings?

Comment: The error is "undefined method `has_topic_headings?' ". I had previously tried to change the function name, hence causing the confusion. I edited the post.

Comment: Even if I change the function to 
    def has_topic_headings?
        1
    end

The result is the same

Comment: Ok, I have reviewed it again. You are calling has_topic_headings? on subcategory model which you'll never be able to reach. So you have to define this method in subcategory model. Hope I am clear now.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your method :

```
<%= link_to subcategory.name, subcategory, data: :has_topic_headings %>
```

Edit: Sorry for misunderstanding. the error is in your data which you are passing in your link:

```
data: :has_topic_headings
```

rails is asking for above method, not for `has_topic_headings?`

Edit: Yes, as @techvineet said, you cannot call a helper method on a subcategory object.
you should write method in your subcategory model:

```
 def has_topic_headings?
    return true if self.topic_headings
 end
```

Or you can do this in your helper class:

```
def has_topic_headings(subcategory)
   return true if subcategory.topic_headings
end
```

and in your form, call it like this:

```
<%if has_topic_headings(subcategory) %>
  <%= link_to subcategory.name, subcategory, data: :has_topic_headings %>
<% else %>
  <%= link_to subcategory.name, subcategory %>
<% end %>
```

Hope it will help.Thanks

Comment: No, the error is in the line <%if subcategory.has_topic_headings? %>, the line you refer to is just a data attribute for the anchor tag

Comment: Then the error should be undefined method `has_topic_headings?' for #<Subcategory:0xa68748c>

Comment: The error is "undefined method `has_topic_headings?' ". I had previously tried to change the function name, hence causing the confusion. I edited the post.